# update Select list with two dates

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm new on apex and I have this basic question.

I have two datepickers and a select list that depends on those datetimepickers. I need to update the query that fills up the Select List when any datetimepickers change. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to **List of values** group of properties.

One of them is the **Cascading LOV Parent Item(s)** property. Enter names of those datepicker items in there, e.g.

```
:P1_DATE_FROM, :P1_DATE_TO
```